# Can't get listbox to display

Tags: listbox

I am stuck here. I can't get the solution to print out into the listbox. I just can't find out what I am missing. I need help. Anything you see would be a big help. This is all the code from my program:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For years As Integer = 3 To 20
        Lifebox.Items.Add(years.ToString)
    Next years
    Lifebox.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub CloseButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CloseButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub DisplayButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DisplayButton.Click
    Dim cost As Double
    Dim life As Double
    Dim period As Double
    Dim numberperiod As Double
    Dim salvage As Double
    Dim depreciation As Double
    Dim isConvertedCost As Boolean
    Dim isConvertedLife As Boolean
    Dim isConvertedSalvage As Boolean

    isConvertedCost = Double.TryParse(Assetbox.Text, cost)
    isConvertedLife = Double.TryParse(Lifebox.Text, life)
    isConvertedSalvage = Double.TryParse(SalavageBox.Text, salvage)

    For numberperiod = 1 To period Step 1
        depreciation = Financial.DDB(cost, salvage, life, numberperiod)
        DepBox.Text += numberperiod.ToString & " -> " & Convert.ToString(depreciation) _
        & ControlChars.NewLine
    Next numberperiod


    If isConvertedCost AndAlso isConvertedLife AndAlso isConvertedSalvage Then
        DepBox.Text = "    Year    Depreciation   "






    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The cost, life, and salvage values must be numeric.",
                        "Sonheim Manufacturing Company", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Assetbox.Focus()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: This is clearly **not** VBA, I removed the tag.

Comment: It would also be useful to describe *where* the problem is. It is not immediately clear to me which object is your "listBox", nor what it *should* be doing or displaying, etc.

Comment: Not VBScript either. Pulled that tag.

Comment: pretty sure it's VB.net so I have tagged it accordingly.

Comment: DepBox   is my list list box

Comment: The application should use the double-declining balance method to calculate the depreciation... using Financial.DDB method to calculate depreciation. The method's syntax is Financial.DDB(cost, salvage, life, period). In the syntax, the cost, salvage, and life arguments are the asset's cost, salvage, value, and useful life. The period argument is the period for which you want the depreciation amount calculated